# What Datatypes should i use for following requirement in C#

Tags: c#, types, double, decimal

First I will explain the name of different properties and function that will be performed on them. 
Afterwards you tell me which datatype should i use for them ??

1) Gross Weight(user will enter) : Will be in quintals(weight category). **For Example :** 147.3800.

2) Less Tear(user will enter : Also be in quintals(weight category). **For Example :** .3800.

3) Net Weight(Auto-Computed) : In quintals(weight category). **For Example :** GrossWeight - Less Tear.

4) Rate/Quintal(user will enter) : Amount for per quintal. **For Example :** 4560.55

5) Total Amount(Auto-Computed) : **For Example :** NetWeight x Rate/Quintal

Now tell me the preferable data-types for above five fields in C#.

Comment: Homework perhaps? Anyway, "please" would have been nice.

Comment: lol.....well it's not a homework....actually i had doubts about double and decimal. I read somewhere that for money types decimal is optimum and currently i am using double in my app.
Sorry in case you feel offended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When possible, use `decimal` for money (#4 and #5) to avoid floating-point representation errors.

For physical measurements like weight, or for irrational-valued functions like `sin` or `log`, prefer `double`.

Comment: hmm....i will .....but what to do in case where calculations involved properties other than money-related. Like in my example, TotalAmount is calculation over multiplication of Rate/Quintal and NetWeight. Should i use decimal for net weight too ??

Comment: If you want, you can use `decimal` for everything just to avoid mixing types.  However, different types have different purposes.  Integers are used for **counting discrete** items.  `float` and `double` are for **approximations** of **continuous** data.  Money is unique in that it's a **discrete** quantity but counted in units of 0.01 instead of 1.  For this purpose, it's problematic that `0.01` in a `double` really means 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375.  So the `decimal` type was introduced to allow amounts of money to be represented exactly...

Comment: The disadvantage of decimal arithmetic is that, being implemented in software instead of hardware, it's a *lot* slower than binary floating-point.  For this reason, I recommend against `decimal` unless you *need* an exact representation of 0.1 and 0.01.

Answer (score 2):

In every case you probably want to use a floating point value, which means a decision between double and decimal.

Since .NET lacks objects dealing with arbitrary-precision floating point operations, the choice is connected mostly with precision and range. Decimal has smaller range (from 10e-28 up to 7.9 x 10e28, but better precision (28-29 significant digits). Double works the other way round (range from ~10e-324 to ~10e308 and 15-16 digits).

For this scenario I would recommend using decimals in all cases.

Comment: the problem with decimals is that you can't use for filling data of nature float. Like i can't fill a texbox binded to a decimal with 2.56